# Why does C# skip a statement?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, while-loop, switch-statement, console-application

Using MS Visual Studio 2010 and the program is based in C# Console Application.

I have a `while` loop with an `sInput = Console.ReadLine();` and then a `switch` inside.

When I run my code the `sInput` is skipped in the first occurrence of the `while` loop (Which automatically gives the `default` value of the `switch`).

But it works properly from the second occurrence of the `While` loop.

Why does it skip `sInput` in the first occurrence?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;

namespace game_Console
{
    class Program
    {
        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", ExactSpelling = true)]

    private static extern IntPtr GetConsoleWindow();
    private static IntPtr ThisConsole = GetConsoleWindow();

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]

    private static extern bool ShowWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int nCmdShow);
    private const int HIDE = 0;
    private const int MAXIMIZE = 3;
    private const int MINIMIZE = 6;
    private const int RESTORE = 9;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.SetWindowSize(Console.LargestWindowWidth, Console.LargestWindowHeight);
        ShowWindow(ThisConsole, MAXIMIZE);

        string sMenu, sIntro, sInput;
        bool bExit, bCredits;

        sMenu = "********************\n Pokemon Console\n********************\n\n Type in the desired number(1-5) and press Enter.\n--------------------\n 1. New Game\n 2. How To Play\n 3. High Scores\n 4. Credits\n 5. Exit\n____________________\n";
        sIntro = "\n        ########  ########  ##    ##  ########  ##    ##  ########  ##    ##        ########  ########  ##    ##  ########  ########  ##        ########\n        ########  ########  ##   ##   ########  ###  ###  ########  ###   ##        ########  ########  ###   ##  ########  ########  ##        ########\n        ##    ##  ##    ##  ##  ##    ##        ## ## ##  ##    ##  ###   ##        ##    ##  ##    ##  ###   ##  ##        ##    ##  ##        ##\n        ##    ##  ##    ##  ## ##     ##        ## ## ##  ##    ##  ## #  ##        ##        ##    ##  ## #  ##  ##        ##    ##  ##        ##\n        ########  ##    ##  ###       ####      ##    ##  ##    ##  ## #  ##        ##        ##    ##  ## #  ##  ########  ##    ##  ##        ####\n        ########  ##    ##  ###       ####      ##    ##  ##    ##  ##  # ##        ##        ##    ##  ##  # ##  ########  ##    ##  ##        ####\n        ##        ##    ##  ## ##     ##        ##    ##  ##    ##  ##  # ##        ##        ##    ##  ##  # ##        ##  ##    ##  ##        ##\n        ##        ##    ##  ##  ##    ##        ##    ##  ##    ##  ##   ###        ##    ##  ##    ##  ##   ###        ##  ##    ##  ##        ##\n        ##        ########  ##   ##   ########  ##    ##  ########  ##   ###        ########  ########  ##   ###  ########  ########  ########  ########\n        ##        ########  ##    ##  ########  ##    ##  ########  ##    ##        ########  ########  ##    ##  ########  ########  ########  ########\n ______________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________\n                                                                      Press Enter to continue";
        bExit = false;
        bCredits = false;

        Image Picture = Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\Home\Desktop\pokemon console\Pokemon Console\Pokemon Console\Data\pokemon\pics\00.png");
        Console.SetBufferSize((Picture.Width * 0x2), (Picture.Height * 0x2));
        FrameDimension Dimension = new FrameDimension(Picture.FrameDimensionsList[0x0]);
        int FrameCount = Picture.GetFrameCount(Dimension);
        int Left = Console.WindowLeft, Top = Console.WindowTop;
        char[] Chars = { '#', '#', '@', '%', '=', '+', '*', ':', '-', '.', ' ' };
        Picture.SelectActiveFrame(Dimension, 0x0);
        for (int i = 0x0; i < Picture.Height; i++)
        {
            for (int x = 0x0; x < Picture.Width; x++)
            {
                Color Color = ((Bitmap)Picture).GetPixel(x, i);
                int Gray = (Color.R + Color.G + Color.B) / 0x3;
                int Index = (Gray * (Chars.Length - 0x1)) / 0xFF;
                Console.Write(Chars[Index]);
            }
            Console.Write('\n');
        }


        Console.WriteLine(sIntro);
        Console.Read();
        Console.Clear();

        while (bExit == false)
        {
            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine(sMenu);
            sInput = Console.ReadLine();//Skips this line in the first occurrence

            switch (sInput)
            {
                case "1":
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("one");
                    Console.ReadLine();
                    break;
                }
                case "2":
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("two");
                    Console.ReadLine();
                    break;
                }
                case "3":
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("three");
                    Console.ReadLine();
                    break;
                }
                case "4":
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("four");
                    Console.ReadLine();
                    break;
                }
                case "5":
                {
                    bExit = true;
                    break;
                }
                default:
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("error");
                    Console.ReadLine();
                    break;
                }                    
            }

        }

        Console.Clear();
        if (bCredits == false)
        {                
            Console.WriteLine(" Take a look at our Credits before you leave");
            TextReader tr = new StreamReader("Credits.txt");
            Console.WriteLine(tr.ReadToEnd());
            tr.Close();
        }
        Console.WriteLine("\n +++++++++++++++++++++++++\n ++Thank you for playing++\n +++++++++++++++++++++++++\n\n    Press Enter to Exit");
        Console.Read();
        Console.Read();
    }
}
}
```

**EDIT**:Added all my code to establish if problem originated from previous code outside the while loop.

Comment: Tested your code, it works for me. Maybe the code is not actually compiling your changes?

Comment: Add a breakpoint to `switch(sInput)` and check the value of `sInput`?

Comment: After the breakpoint the value of `sInput` is `""`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that input buffer is not empty and contains newline. Could it be that your provided code is taken out of context where some other data input occurs?

Try to add following code before skipped line:

```
while (Console.KeyAvailable)
    Console.ReadKey(true);
```

Comment: The line is still being skipped

Comment: Aren't you using ENTER key for passing first `Console.Read();` before `while` loop? If so, try to hit some other char (for instance, 'a') and check if it works.

Comment: Did as you mentioned and then changed then  `Console.Read()` to `Console.ReadLine()` which worked.